# How to serve a temporary file (non-static) via HTTP request?

Tags: python, django, http, temporary-files

I have a Python REST server, that is able to download and write a temporary file using Python TempFile.
That is, at request time I have a a file in the filesystem of the server, but it is not permanent so the client cannot access it statically (I.e. via http://myserver/path-to-my-file ). I need a way to access an *endpoint*, and then get a file returned based on the request. (I.e. http://myserver/myendpoint/myrequestparameters)

How does that work over HTTP? Is it possible?

(For context, right now I am serving the file encoded as string using base64 encoding and utf-8 decoding, but my frontend application needs a direct download link)

Comment: So create endpoint that reads file and returns it, where is exact problem you are facing, what did you try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a [dedicated response type for such stuff in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects). Assuming send_file is your endpoint:

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def send_file(response):

    img = open('my_image_file.jpg', 'rb')

    response = FileResponse(img)

    return response
```

Comment: Nice! Django FileResponse definitely seems like what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.